# Laravel 5 Update Validation email needs to be unique

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to update a user, as an admin.

I'm changing the username, but it says email must be unique.

How do I fix this.

```
public function update($id, PutUser $request)
{
if (auth()->id() == $id) {
    return redirect()->back()->withFlashDanger('Permission Denied, You can not edit own profile here.');
}

$user = User::find($id);


$user->update((array_merge($request->validated(), ['county' => request('county')])));

//Update model_has_roles model with assignees_roles



return redirect()->route('users.index')->withFlashSuccess(trans("alerts.users.updated"));
}
```

This is the request class

```
     public function authorize()
     {
         return true;
     }

     public function rules()
     {
         $user_id =  $this->input('id');

         return [
           'name' => 'required|string',
           'username' => 'required',
           'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email'.$user_id,
           'gender' => 'required',
           'phone' => 'sometimes|numeric',
           'address' => 'sometimes|string',
           'country_id' => 'required',
         ];
     }
}
```

I keep getting a failed email validation. 'Email has already been taken'. Any idea

Comment: I have tried to answer your question. Did it solve your problem? If so, please mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a comma after the `email` label in your validation:

```
return [
    'name' => 'required|string',
    'username' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$user_id,
    'gender' => 'required',
    'phone' => 'sometimes|numeric',
    'address' => 'sometimes|string',
    'country_id' => 'required',
];
```

Since Laravel 5.3 (I believe), you can also use rule builders for more descriptive validation rules. Those are better to read and interpret for humans so it would result in a lower error rate:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

return [
    'email' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('users', 'email')->except($user_id),
    ]
];
```

https://medium.com/@tomgrohl/why-you-should-be-using-rule-objects-in-laravel-5-5-c2505e729b40